# Jasig CAS, how to redirect view after successful login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cas, jasig

in my scenario, user need to change password before first times login.
how to make cas redirect url before login page?

in my app, i already define my own controller to handle certain URL, and also implement my own  custom authentication under authenticationHandlers.

now only left this mechanism reset password before login.

can anyone give me a clue how to do it?

my maven project file:
https://qeyg6a.bay.livefilestore.com/y2msQyFts1aCgGkYR4ybMses2mGFVNJBLCX_xQ9pDi8gVdnhx9P5ibVVBlg6p6T9RM3BAN8Qcz2Izo5JGdQzbyU-kSMTIwBVOYhkdG1RvsyE50/cas-server-webapp.rar?download&psid=1

My login-webflow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

    Licensed to Jasig under one or more contributor license
    agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work
    for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    Jasig licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
    Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
    except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a
    copy of the License at the following location:

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
    KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.

-->
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="credentials" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentials" />
    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="initialFlowSetupAction" />
    </on-start>

    <decision-state id="ticketGrantingTicketExistsCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.ticketGrantingTicketId != null" then="hasServiceCheck" else="gatewayRequestCheck" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="gatewayRequestCheck">
        <if test="requestParameters.gateway != '' and requestParameters.gateway != null and flowScope.service != null" then="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" else="serviceAuthorizationCheck" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="hasServiceCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="renewRequestCheck" else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="renewRequestCheck">
        <if test="requestParameters.renew != '' and requestParameters.renew != null" then="serviceAuthorizationCheck" else="generateServiceTicket" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- Do a service authorization check early without the need to login first -->
    <action-state id="serviceAuthorizationCheck">
        <evaluate expression="serviceAuthorizationCheck"/>
        <transition to="generateLoginTicket"/>
    </action-state>

    <!-- 
        The "warn" action makes the determination of whether to redirect directly to the requested
        service or display the "confirmation" page to go back to the server.
    -->
    <decision-state id="warn">
        <if test="flowScope.warnCookieValue" then="showWarningView" else="redirect" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- 
    <action-state id="startAuthenticate">
        <action bean="x509Check" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
        <transition on="warn" to="warn" />
        <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
    </action-state>
     -->

    <!--
        LPPE transitions begin here: You will also need to
        move over the 'lppe-configuration.xml' file from the
        'unused-spring-configuration' folder to the 'spring-configuration' folder
        so CAS can pick up the definition for the bean 'passwordPolicyAction'.
    -->
    <action-state id="passwordPolicyCheck">
        <evaluate expression="passwordPolicyAction" />
        <transition on="showWarning" to="passwordServiceCheck" />
        <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
        <transition on="error" to="viewLoginForm" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="passwordServiceCheck">
        <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
        <transition to="passwordPostCheck" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="passwordPostCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="warnPassRedirect" else="pwdWarningPostView" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="warnPassRedirect">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to="pwdWarningPostView" />
        <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" />
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="pwdWarningAbstractView">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="flowScope.passwordPolicyUrl" value="passwordPolicyAction.getPasswordPolicyUrl()" />
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>
    <end-state id="pwdWarningPostView" view="casWarnPassView" parent="#pwdWarningAbstractView" />
    <end-state id="casExpiredPassView" view="casExpiredPassView" parent="#pwdWarningAbstractView" />
    <end-state id="casMustChangePassView" view="casMustChangePassView" parent="#pwdWarningAbstractView" />
    <end-state id="casAccountDisabledView" view="casAccountDisabledView" />
    <end-state id="casAccountLockedView" view="casAccountLockedView" />
    <end-state id="casBadHoursView" view="casBadHoursView" />
    <end-state id="casBadWorkstationView" view="casBadWorkstationView" />
    <!-- LPPE transitions end here... -->

    <action-state id="generateLoginTicket">
        <evaluate expression="generateLoginTicketAction.generate(flowRequestContext)" />
        <transition on="generated" to="viewLoginForm" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="viewLoginForm" view="casLoginView" model="credentials">
        <binder>
            <binding property="username" />
            <binding property="password" />
        </binder>
        <on-entry>
            <set name="viewScope.commandName" value="'credentials'" />
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="submit" bind="true" validate="true" to="realSubmit">
            <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.doBind(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials)" />
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="realSubmit">
        <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.credentials, messageContext)" />
        <!--
          To enable LPPE on the 'warn' replace the below transition with:
          <transition on="warn" to="passwordPolicyCheck" />

          CAS will attempt to transition to the 'warn' when there's a 'renew' parameter
          and there exists a ticketGrantingId and a service for the incoming request.
        -->
        <transition on="warn" to="warn" />
        <!--
          To enable LPPE on the 'success' replace the below transition with:
          <transition on="success" to="passwordPolicyCheck" />
        -->
        <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
        <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
        <transition on="accountDisabled" to="casAccountDisabledView" />
        <transition on="mustChangePassword" to="casMustChangePassView" />
        <transition on="accountLocked" to="casAccountLockedView" />
        <transition on="badHours" to="casBadHoursView" />
        <transition on="badWorkstation" to="casBadWorkstationView" />
        <transition on="passwordExpired" to="casExpiredPassView" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="sendTicketGrantingTicket">
        <evaluate expression="sendTicketGrantingTicketAction" />
        <transition to="serviceCheck" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="serviceCheck">
        <if test="flowScope.service != null" then="generateServiceTicket" else="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="generateServiceTicket">
        <evaluate expression="generateServiceTicketAction" />
        <transition on="success" to ="warn" />
        <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
        <transition on="gateway" to="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="gatewayServicesManagementCheck">
        <evaluate expression="gatewayServicesManagementCheck" />
        <transition on="success" to="redirect" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="redirect">
        <evaluate expression="flowScope.service.getResponse(requestScope.serviceTicketId)" result-type="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.Response" result="requestScope.response" />
        <transition to="postRedirectDecision" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="postRedirectDecision">
        <if test="requestScope.response.responseType.name() == 'POST'" then="postView" else="redirectView" />
    </decision-state>

    <!-- 
        the "viewGenericLogin" is the end state for when a user attempts to login without coming directly from a service.
        They have only initialized their single-sign on session.
    -->
    <end-state id="viewGenericLoginSuccess" view="casLoginGenericSuccessView" />

    <!-- 
        The "showWarningView" end state is the end state for when the user has requested privacy settings (to be "warned") to be turned on.  It delegates to a 
        view defines in default_views.properties that display the "Please click here to go to the service." message.
    -->
    <end-state id="showWarningView" view="casLoginConfirmView" />

    <end-state id="postView" view="postResponseView">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="requestScope.parameters" value="requestScope.response.attributes" />
            <set name="requestScope.originalUrl" value="flowScope.service.id" />
        </on-entry>
    </end-state>

    <!-- 
        The "redirect" end state allows CAS to properly end the workflow while still redirecting
        the user back to the service required.
    -->
    <end-state id="redirectView" view="externalRedirect:${requestScope.response.url}" />

    <end-state id="viewServiceErrorView" view="viewServiceErrorView" />

    <end-state id="viewServiceSsoErrorView" view="viewServiceSsoErrorView" />

    <global-transitions>
        <!-- CAS-1023 This one is simple - redirects to a login page (same as renew) when 'ssoEnabled' flag is unchecked
             instead of showing an intermediate unauthorized view with a link to login page -->
        <transition to="viewLoginForm" on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedSsoServiceException"/>
        <transition to="viewServiceErrorView" on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.NoSuchFlowExecutionException" />
        <transition to="viewServiceErrorView" on-exception="org.jasig.cas.services.UnauthorizedServiceException" />
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

## My Solution

1. create

> ```
> resetPasswordView.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
> resetPasswordView.url=/WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/ResetPassword.jsp
> ```

in default_views.properties

1. create

> ```
> public class testflowAction extends AbstractAction{
>     private String origin;
>
>     @Override
>     protected Event doExecute(RequestContext rc) throws Exception {
>         origin = rc.getRequestParameters().get("service");
>         if(true)
>             return result("setNew");
>         else
>             return result("setNew");
>     }
>
> }
> ```

1. in login-wenflow.xml, replace

`<transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />` with
`<transition on="success" to="customFlowCheck" />`

also add

> ```
> <action-state id="customFlowCheck">
>         <evaluate expression="customCheckAction" />
>   <transition on="ok" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
>   <transition on="setNew" to="resetPasswordView" />
> </action-state>
> ```

and

```
<end-state id="resetPasswordView" view="resetPasswordView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem in our company. The user had to be redirected to another page after successful login.
We decided to add another outcome from action state id "realSubmit", that would indicate continuation of flow. 
I would suggest that you first let user to preform login, so he confirms that he's the right user. To do so you need to change submit method in your AuthenticationViaFormAction class. Then you need to destroy TGT, and redirect user to your custom Flow Action that reset password.
It would look something like this:

```
    public final String submit(final RequestContext context, final Credentials credentials, final MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
    (...)
    //Login user, so we know that provided password is correct.
     WebUtils.putTicketGrantingTicketInRequestScope(context, this.centralAuthenticationService.createTicketGrantingTicket(credentials));
    // do custom logic, that check if it is first login attept:
    if( firstLoginAttempt(credentials) {
      //destroy TGT, so user won't stay logged-in after interrupting next step
      centralAuthenticationService.destroyTicketGrantingTicket(ticketGrantingTicketId);
      //redirect user to another action that will handle changing password
      return "changePassRequired"
    }
```

I don't know how you check if the password IS initial password, so I leave it to you. Next add transition in login-webflow.xml outcome:

```
    <action-state id="realSubmit">
    <evaluate expression="authenticationViaFormAction.submit(flowRequestContext,flowScope.credentials, messageContext)" />
    <transition on="warn" to="warn" />
    <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
    <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />
    <transition on="accountDisabled" to="casAccountDisabledView" />
    <transition on="mustChangePassword" to="casMustChangePassView" />
    <transition on="accountLocked" to="casAccountLockedView" />
    <transition on="badHours" to="casBadHoursView" />
    <transition on="badWorkstation" to="casBadWorkstationView" />
    <transition on="passwordExpired" to="casExpiredPassView" />
    <transition on="changePassRequired" to="changePasswordPrepare" />
</action-state>
```

And add custom action, you might as well use the same form as in login action so break it into two states, for example:

```
<view-state id="changePasswordPrepare" view="resetPasswordView">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="resetPasswordAction.setupForm(flowRequestContext)" />
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="submit" bind="true" validate="true" to="resetPasswordRealAction">
    </transition>
</view-state>
<action-state id="resetPasswordRealAction">
    <evaluate expression="resetPasswordAction.submit(flowRequestContext)" />
    <transition on="success" to="sendTicketGrantingTicket" />
    <transition on="again" to="changePasswordPrepare" />
    <transition on="error" to="generateLoginTicket" />       
</action-state>
```

resetPasswordAction.setupForm will prepare custom view with reset password form if it's needed
resetPasswordAction.submit will get variables from your form, and preform changing password.
snippet of class might look somewhat like this:

```
public class resetPasswordAction extends FormAction {
  public final String submit(final RequestContext context) throws Exception {
    final Credentials previousCredentials = context.getFlowScope().get("loginCredentials");
    final String oldPass = context.getConversationScope().get("pass");
    final String newPassword = context.getConversationScope().get("password");
    final String newPasswordagain = context.getConversationScope().get("passwordagain");
    if (!newPassword.equals(newPasswordagain) {
      return "again";
    }
    if ( everythingIsOk(previousCredentials.getUsername(),oldPass,newPassword)) {
      Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials();
      credentials.setUsername(previousCredentials.getUsername());
      credentials.setPassword(newPassword);
      WebUtils.putTicketGrantingTicketInRequestScope(context, this.casService.createTicketGrantingTicket(credentials));
      return "success";
    }
    return "error";
  }
  public Event setupForm(RequestContext context) throws Exception {
    final Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    context.getFlashScope().put("language",locale);
    context.getFlashScope().put("service",context.getRequestScope().get("service");
  }
}
```

You might as well be interested in [CAM](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAM/Home) - CAS account management module, although it seems to be in early, theoretical phase.

You might as well be interested in [cas 4](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS4UM/Architecture), now in beta release as it seems to contain more elastic authentication logic. One, that you could use to do after login password reset.

Answer (score 0):

I have running a CAS Server, seems that you should customize through Spring WebFlow. Follow my glue:

```
    <action-state id="validateForgotPassword">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="flashScope.pmTask" value="'forceChangePassword'"/>
    </on-entry>

    <evaluate expression="forgotPasswordTokenValidateAction" />
    <transition on="success" to="passwordManager"/>
    <transition on="error" to="badForgotPasswordTokenView" />
</action-state>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks your for guiding, could you please give me more info about this? this code should put into login-webflow which part? and how to trigger and implement it? where to run my own code? appreciate if you teach me more.

Comment: Man for a complete answer take a look in LPPE(LDAP Password Police Enforcement), the proper CAS has a solution here [link](https://wiki.jasig.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=55543468) and there is this complete solution here [link](https://github.com/ivanzito/cas-password-manager)

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look then will be back to flag your answer.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, ur example does give me a clue, however in my situations, i am not using ldap authentication, and i need to do my own authentication and other things. therefore i implements my own flow to intercept it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a JS script in succes login witch redirect a from your specific URL

document.location.href ="http://www...."

You can personnalized your processing JS.